# Can I delete records from Amazon Timestream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

Executing a delete query on an Amazon Timestream DB.

When executing this query:

```
delete from "data-api-timestream-test"."test_table"
```

I get the error:

```
The query syntax is invalid at line 1:1
```

Can I delete records from Amazon Timestream?

Answer (score 13):

**Unfortunately, AWS Timestream does not support [deletes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/writes.html) right now.**

The only supported operations are inserts and upserts.

Comment: Is there any work around to update the record data?

Comment: You can upsert records by including the Version in record definition while sending a WriteRecords request. Amazon Timestream will store the record with the record with highest Version. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.write.html

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can not delete the records from timestream database, but you can delete a table via AWS TimeStream SDK. I am attaching a code sample in golang, but you can also do it with Python, Java and bunch of other languages.

```
deleteTableInput := &timestreamwrite.DeleteTableInput{
    DatabaseName:   aws.String(*databaseName),
    TableName:    aws.String(*tableName),
}
_, err = writeSvc.DeleteTable(deleteTableInput)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:")
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Table deleted", *tableName)
}
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.delete-table.html